# DataGridView_CellEndEdit event (C#)

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I am working on editing the values in DataGridViews and consequently updating the new value in the database. I am using CellEndEdit() event to store the new value. However, since I need to edit multiple DataGridViews, can i use the "CellEndEdit" event only once,making it common for all the DataGrids instead of initializing this eent for each DataGrids?

I am using the eventHandler like this:

```
classViewDataGrid1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(classViewDataGrid1_CellEndEdit);

private void classViewDataGrid1_CellEndEdit(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)            
{
   string newValue = classViewDataGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
   string attribValue = classViewDataGrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString();
   EditClassProperties.editProp(newValue, attribValue, EditdDbProp.selNode); //Calling the function that updates database.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what the  `sender` part is for in `EventHandler`. I suggest give [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) a good read.

You could change your code to this, if you want the exact same eventhandler for your other DataGridViews.

```
classViewDataGrid1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(classViewDataGrid1_CellEndEdit);

private void classViewDataGrid1_CellEndEdit(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)            
{
   var dgv = (DataGridView) sender;
   string newValue = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
   string attribValue = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString();
   EditClassProperties.editProp(newValue, attribValue, EditdDbProp.selNode); //Calling the function that updates database.
}
```

Comment: That is an option.
But what I want is.. I have 7 dataGridViews in my application. So i want to edit the values of all the dataGridViews accordingly using a single "CellEndEdit" event instead of using 7 different events of each dataGridView.

What u suggested was not helpful in this regard. If you can suggest me some other.
Anyway thanks for helping.

Comment: You can pass this EventHandler to all the other DataGridViews and it will fetch the values from the corresponding DataGridView. By using `sender` it knows which DataGridView is calling the event. To me it seems that this is exactly what you want, if I'm wrong please add code of the EventHandler for a second DataGridView to help me understand what you're trying to achieve.